# Retrieve all state from GenServer

Tags: elixir

I have a an array of atoms for state in my GenServer. I don't want to just pop off the the last item in the queue, I want to pop off all the state at once.

#### Current Code (NOT WORKING)

```
defmodule ScoreTableQueue do
  use GenServer

  @impl true
  def init(stack) do
    {:ok, stack}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_call(:pop, _from, [state]) do
    {:reply, [state]}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_cast({:push, item}, state) do
    {:noreply, [item | state]}
  end
end
```

#### State of GenServer:

```
{:status, #PID<0.393.0>, {:module, :gen_server},
 [
   [
     "$initial_call": {ScoreTableQueue, :init, 1},
     "$ancestors": [#PID<0.383.0>, #PID<0.74.0>]
   ],
   :running,
   #PID<0.393.0>,
   [],
   [
     header: 'Status for generic server <0.393.0>',
     data: [
       {'Status', :running},
       {'Parent', #PID<0.393.0>},
       {'Logged events', []}
     ],
     data: [{'State', [:code, :hello, :world]}]
   ]
 ]}
```

I'm want to return `[:code, :hello, :world]` when I call `GenServer.call(pid, :pop)` How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
@impl true
def handle_call(:pop, _from, [state]) do
  {:reply, [state]}
end
```

to

```
 @impl true
 def handle_call(:pop, _from, [state]) do
  {:reply, state, []}
 end
```

You are basically returning the state and setting the current state to empty list

[`handle_call/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:handle_call/3) returns a tuple in the format

`{:reply, reply, new_state}`

In your case you want to reply the current state and set the new state to empty list.

`{:reply, state, []}`

or if you want to return the current state without resetting the stack

`{:reply, state, state}`